# ListView Headers Don't Show Up

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, listview

I am doing a windows mobile application 6.1.

I dragged in a listview and went to columns and added columns to my list view. When I run the listview they do not show up.

I then tried to add them through C# code on page load with the follow code.

```
ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
            header.Text = "gkgag";
            header.Width = 100;
            header.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            listView1.Columns.Add(header);
```

this does not work either. Why don't they show up?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You must use detailed view for column headers to be visible.

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

If that´s not the problem, column headers might be hidden behind windows systembar.

Comment: In my case the headers were behind a MenuStrip. I put the menustrip and listview in a tablelayoutpanel to solve this problem.

Comment: In my case, i was saving and then loading the column widths from the .config file of the app when the window opened and they happened to be zero. Sigh

Comment: In a thousand years or longer, I would never be able to guess that's the answer.  I'll be driving a million circles without the assurance of finding this.  Thanks!

Comment: I had to set HeaderStyle to something not "None"