# Winform listview columns not showing up

Tags: windows, vb.net, listview

I'm trying to put a listview on a VS 2010, vb.net winform form.  I 
1. drug the listview from the toolbox to the form.
2. right cick and did an edit columns
3. added two columns with the names of (chLocationID, chLocation) and the text of LocationID and Location.
4.  when i click ok, nothing shows up in the listview designer.

In the code behind i did a for loop to add some data.

```
  For Each O In oS
        Dim itm As New ListViewItem
        itm.SubItems.Add(O.tblLocationID.ToString)
        itm.SubItems.Add(O.Location)
        itm.Tag = O
        lvLocation.Items.Add(itm)
    Next
```

when i step through the code.. it says that it adds the row.. a lvLocation.items.count give me a value of 1.. which is correct but nothing displays on the screen.

So.. I've done something wrong.. just not sure what?

Comment: thanks for qurey... this will help for got solutions..

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView Headers Don't Show Up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936798/listview-headers-dont-show-up)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure the ListView's View property is set to Details - either in the designer or in code.  Winforms ListViews only show their columns in Details view.

Comment: thank you.. that did it.  if i could ask a follow up question... in the for loop above, it's adding the tblLocationID.tostring to the second column instead of the first. i didn't see any property on the add to give it the column location.

Comment: well.. if i changed the code to read this.. Dim itm As New ListViewItem(O.tblLocationID.ToString)
            itm.SubItems.Add(O.Location) it seems to use the columns they way i was thinking it would

Comment: glad you found the solution - sorry for not getting back to you - didn't have a chance to get online last night.

Comment: Sri - you should repost your question as a separate question; I'm not sure I have a good answer for you right now, & you won't get much response with it posted under an answered question.

Also - it would be helpful to see a sample of the code you're using to populate the list.  Are you using 'Details' view?

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you!