# Listview column Header not displaying VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

I am not getting column Header in listView. only one item(0) is displaying not the sub Item. here is my code. tell me what is wrong in it. 
Thank you in advance.

```
Dim PTCode As Integer = CInt(ChildPatnameTag)
ClearSQl()

    CheckState()
    strSql = "select tCode,tprice from patTests where pCode=" & PTCode
    strConn.Open()
    Dim TCmdSelect As New OleDbCommand(strSql, strConn)
    Dim TReader As OleDbDataReader = TCmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
    'Column Header
    Dim header1, header2 As ColumnHeader
    header1 = New ColumnHeader
    header1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    header1.Text = "Test"
    header1.Width = 250
    header2 = New ColumnHeader
    header2.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    header2.Text = "Price"
    header2.Width = 50
    With lvwPatTests
        .CheckBoxes = True
        .GridLines = True
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .HideSelection = False
        .MultiSelect = False
        .Columns.Add("Test")
        .Columns.Add("Price")
    End With
    If TReader.HasRows Then
        Do While TReader.Read
            ClearSQl()
            strSql = "Select tName from tests where tCode=" & TReader("tCode")
            Dim TCCmdSelect As New OleDbCommand(strSql, strConn)
            Dim TCReader As OleDbDataReader = TCCmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
            If TCReader.HasRows Then
                Do While TCReader.Read
                      For i = 0 To TCReader.FieldCount - 1
                        ' Create List View Item (Row)  
                       Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
                        ' First Column can be the listview item's Text  
                        lvi.Text = TCReader.Item("tName").ToString
                        ' Second Column is the first sub item  
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(TReader.Item("tprice"))
                        MsgBox(TCReader.Item("tName").ToString)
                        MsgBox(TReader.Item("tprice"))
                        ' Add the ListViewItem to the ListView  
                        lvwPatTests.Items.Add(lvi)
                    Next
                Loop
                TCCmdSelect.Dispose()
                TCReader.Close()
                TCReader = Nothing
            Else
                TCCmdSelect.Dispose()
                TCReader.Close()
                TCReader = Nothing
            End If
        Loop
        TReader.Close()
        TReader = Nothing
    End If
```

Comment: It's pointless to set objects equal to `Nothing`. And while you do need to call the `Dispose` method on objects that implement `IDisposable`, it's better to wrap their creation in a `Using` statement. There's an awful lot of "noise" in this code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView Headers Don't Show Up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936798/listview-headers-dont-show-up)

Answer (score 12):

You need to change your ListView control's View property to `Details` in order to see the columns and subitems:

```
With lvwPatTests
  .View = View.Details

  .CheckBoxes = True
  .GridLines = True
  .FullRowSelect = True
  .HideSelection = False
  .MultiSelect = False
  .Columns.Add("Test")
  .Columns.Add("Price")
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the objects. Just pass them in:

```
   With lvwPatTests
        .CheckBoxes = True
        .GridLines = True
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .HideSelection = False
        .MultiSelect = False
        .Columns.Add(header1)
        .Columns.Add(header2)
    End With
```